# Обособление приложения. Выбор пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, приложение, причастный-оборот

*Мощным импульсом к качественному изменению и развитию рынков стал универсальный товар — деньги — превратившийся во всеобщий эквивалент стоимости продуктов труда.*

Нужно ли добавить запятую перед вторым тире, т. к. дальше идет причастный оборот?   Возможно ли заменить второе тире просто запятой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что это предложение надо оформить так (с запятой, без второго тире):
*Мощным импульсом к качественному изменению и развитию рынков стал универсальный товар — **деньги,** превратившийся во всеобщий эквивалент стоимости продуктов труда.*

Вот что о такой ситуации говорится у Розенталя (примечание к пункту 10).

> Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
>
> 1. Если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: *Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — **весы,** то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — **акваланг,** можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров...*

Мне кажется, что приложение лучше поставить в самый конец.
*Мощным импульсом к качественному изменению и развитию рынков стал универсальный товар, превратившийся во всеобщий эквивалент стоимости продуктов труда, — **деньги**.*

[Обособленные приложения](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=111)