# Какой знак поставить, если после приложения следует причастный оборот?

Tags: запятые, тире

Мощным импульсом к развитию рынков стал универсальный товар — деньги (?) превратившийся в эквивалент стоимости продуктов труда.

Если деньги - приложение,то лучше выделить запятыми с двух сторон или поставить после "деньги" запятую, чтобы выделить причастный оборот. Или запятую с тире?

Comment: Ася, Вы же уже задавали этот вопрос. По-моему, был дан четкий, однозначный ответ.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464308/Обособление-приложения-Выбор-пунктуации/464309#464309

Comment: Любопытная история… Точно ли  был уже дан «четкий и однозначный ответ» или мы что-то проглядели? Так какое согласование будет правильным, уважаемые участники форума? Не хотели бы вы прокомментировать эту ситуацию?

Comment: Что ж ответов нет, а может быть, и не будет. Проглядели же мы явное отсутствие согласования в обособленном с помощью тире приложении. Да вот только согласование во мн.числе мне также не представляется корректным. Нестандартная задача? Очень может быть...

Comment: @Sharon, я обратил внимание на отсутствие согласования с "деньгами". Мне, как и вам, всё-таки видится ед. число. Может быть, поэтому Римма в конце ответа предложила переставить "деньги" в конец. Автор же вопроса об этом вообще не спрашивает. Тот ответ был принят. Такое ощущение, что повтор произошел по ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я на самом деле считаю оба ответа неверными, здесь история более интересная, чем представляется на первый взгляд. Возможно, я все-таки дам свой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мощным импульсом к развитию рынков стал универсальный товар -деньги, превратившиЕся в эквивалент стоимости продуктов труда.

Answer (score 0):

Так какое же согласование **будет правильным**, в единственном или во множественном числе?  Ведь даны были разные ответы.

1. Раскрывать подробно эту тему **с точки зрения теории**  я в ближайшее время не планирую (нет уверенности, в том, что это нужно, да и настроения как-то нет). Но чтобы как-то поставить точку в начатом разговоре, могу сказать о **практической** стороне вопроса.
2. Я считаю, что конструкции с **обособленным определительным оборотом** (или определительным придаточным предложением) сюда **вообще не подходят**, особенно если требуется **согласование в числе**.

В этом случае оборот **может быть прочитан не так**, как задумано автором (здесь два варианта чтения), что и сделал н**аш участник**, давший этот ответ. Соответственно,  у него есть **все основания** увидеть здесь отсутствие согласования.

Но если обособления в подобных конструкциях нет, то  остается только один произносительный вариант:  ***Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмены  // для участия в парусных гонках.***  Сочетание «первые ласточки — наши спортсмены»  читается в одну фразу, без паузы.

3. Чтобы проверить **правильность этой версии**, надо понаблюдать **за практикой** использования конструкции  в заслуживающих доверия текстах (учебниках, художественной литературе).  Встречается ли там обособление?
4. **Тема же называется так**: Розенталь, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111 § 19. Обособленные приложения, п.10.  Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается (п. 2), если приложение выражает **конкретное** значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее или образное** значение:
5. Вот такая «загадка» от меня для желающих подумать и сделать **свой собственный вывод.** Разные версии на любой вкус: согласование в ед. числе, согласование во мн. числе,  оба вариант подходят, не подходит ни один из вариантов.

**ЛИРИЧЕСКОЕ ОТСТУПЛЕНИЕ ОТ ТЕМЫ**

1. **О собственном мнении**

Собственная оценка существующих взглядов, всегда ли она нужна? Интересен в этом плане **разговор Базарова и Павла Кирсанова** (отрывки из диалогов):

— Вы столь высокого мнения о немцах?

— Тамошние ученые дельный народ.

— Но как же нам Аркадий Николаич сейчас сказывал, что вы не признаете никаких авторитетов? Не верите им?

— Да зачем же я стану их признавать? И чему я буду верить? Мне скажут дело, я соглашаюсь, вот и всё.

— А немцы всё дело говорят?

— Не все…

Позиция Базарова в этом вопросе интересна тем, что он опирается **на  опыт предшественников,** оценивает его и только потом переходит к дальнейшим исследованиям. В противном случае  собственное и независимое суждение  **будет дорогой в никуда.**

2. **Как соотносятся между собой три принципа пунктуации** (мое мнение)

В этой теме хочется сказать несколько слов об ИНТОНАЦИОННОМ АНАЛИЗЕ, которому я посвятила много времени на форуме.  Там наиболее часто возникают **нестандартные ситуации**, требующие собственного решения.

Я считаю, что основным принципом в пунктуации является **смысловой принцип** – нам важно, что мы хотим сказать, кому и зачем это говорим.

Но содержание в языке выражается с помощью двух форм – **грамматической и интонационной.** На грамматическом принципе основаны **правила Розенталя** (именно он раскрыл конкретное содержание  свода 1956 года). **Грамматический принцип** – это как бы основание для решения задачи.

Интонационный принцип используется там, где **одна и та же** грамматика имеет **несколько фонетических форм,** которые различаются смысловыми оттенками.  Без него в этом случае не обойтись, да и Розенталь в   своих правилах часто упоминает интонацию. Интонация является основным средством связи в БСП – куда же без нее! Как еще поставить знаки в бессоюзном сложном предложении?

**Смысловое тонирование** речи – это уникальное свойство нашего языка,  я не уверена, что оно где-то еще применяется. Так почему же нам не уделить интонационному анализу больше внимания, чем это обычно делается.