# Тире или двоеточие? Необходимо разъяснение

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: "Теперь туда и поезда не ходят - "Бостон - Мэн" и прежде проходил стороной, а несколько лет назад закрыли и ветку из Ровлея".

Я не могу понять, почему в данном случае в тексте употребили тире, а не двоеточие, для постановки которого, по моему мнению, гораздо больше оснований.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Теперь туда и поезда не ходят –  "**Бостон – Мэн" и прежде проходил стороной, а несколько лет назад закрыли и ветку из Ровлея.***

**ОТВЕТ ПО ПРАВИЛАМ**

1. Действительно, **почему здесь стоит тире?**  У нас три простых предложения в составе БСП, при этом в предложениях  (2)  и  (3) дается дополнительное пояснение к содержанию предложения (1).  Пояснительная функция является основной для  двоеточия, почему бы не использовать именно этот знак?

§ 44. Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

Пункт 1. Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) раскрывает содержание первой части (между частями можно вставить слова а именно): Погода была ужасная: ветер выл, мокрый снег падал хлопьями (П.);

2. **Но у Розенталя есть еще одна тема**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания.  Двоеточие — тире

Там говорится о **вариативности двоеточия и тире** в БСП с пояснительными отношениями, а также об **«агрессивности»** тире.  Дается объяснение этому явлению: «В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе».

3. Какой же можно сделать вывод?  Постановка тире вместо ожидаемого двоеточия допускается правилами – пусть **автор сам выбирает**, что ему нравится.
4. Это тот ответ, который мы найдем в правилах. Правда, есть **еще кое-что.** Довольно часто у Розенталя указывается следующее: «При отсутствии **предупредительной интонации** двоеточие в этих случаях не ставится».

Не это ли решение нашего вопроса, надо только понять, как выглядит предупредительная интонация.

**ИНТОНАЦИОННЫЙ АНАЛИЗ**

1. Условно можно сказать, что мы используем **два тире** –  присоединительное и разделительное, так как у них разная интонация. При **разделительном** тире голос перед паузой повышается, а  в случае **присоединительного** тире  понижается. В устной речи разное произношение определяется без труда.
2. При постановке **двоеточия** также делается понижение голоса, хотя и неполное, а вот пауза **значительно увеличена** – именно это Розенталь называет предупредительной интонацией.
3. Присоединительное тире **отличается от двоеточия**  более короткой паузой и полным понижением голоса (как и в конце предложения, только остановка  речи короткая). Этим присоединительное тире  немного похоже на точку – мы как будто приостанавливаем речь, а потом добавляем еще какую-то дополнительную информацию.
4. Именно присоединительное тире **конкурирует с двоеточием:** интонация сходная, а все темы (пояснение, изъяснение, причинно-следственные отношения)  смежные. **Так как же сделать выбор?** Здесь сказывается влияние разных факторов – структура конкретного предложения, общая семантика текста и т.д.
5. Если автор поставил  в приведенном предложении тире, то это значит, что дополнительные **пояснения** имеют **присоединительный** характер. Тогда предупредительная пауза  нежелательна, она, по мнению автора, не вписывается в характер текста.  Подробная информация  во второй части БСП как бы вынесена на **второй план** по отношению к общему повествованию.
6. Я привожу такой **подробный анализ** с той целью, чтобы потом можно было ссылаться на тему. Для каждого конкретного предложения все сказанное можно излагать очень коротко.

Comment: Так каков ваш ответ: ставить тире или нет? Честно говоря, не вижу оснований для тире.Несмртря на вариативность знаков, тире всегда вносит дополнительный оттенок. Здесь не тот случай.

Comment: Серж, вот интересное дело. У вас есть свой ответ, вероятно, у многих он тоже есть, но все молчали. Почему? Целый день, если не два висел вопрос, и никто его положительно не отметил и ответов не предложил.

Comment: Я собирался ответить, не успел. Отметил и вопрос и ответы. Тоже тире поставил бы.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Александр, если у ж  нас разговор зашел, то можно вас спросить: вы не хотели бы прокомментировать этот ответ https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464558/Какой-знак-поставить-если-после-приложения-следует-причастный-оборот#comment482887_464558
Вопрос старый, вы его, вероятно, не заметили, но мне кажется, что интересный. Я хотела дать ответ, потом стала сомневаться (а кому он нужен), сейчас же тоже раздумываю (может, все-таки ответить, ведь ответ уже готов). Думаю, что согласование там нужно, а почему я раньше не заметила (философский такой вопрос).

Comment: @Sharon, с т/ф писать развернутые ответы мне неохота, да и тяжело.

Comment: Sharon, мне кажется, присоединительные тире вводит дополнительное разъяснения, замечание.  Поэтому я здесь не вижу присоединительные тире.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за ответ. Наверное, не стоило мне  называть тире присоединительным, это чисто условный термин (он связан с присоединительной, то есть  нисходяще-нисходящей интонацией). В действительности это обычное тире, которое может заменять двоеточие, но у него есть и свои собственные темы.  Мне же важно было связать это тире с присоединительной интонацией и противопоставить его разделительному тире, у которого интонация восходяще-нисходящая.

Comment: Розенталь  в своих правилах  указывает на применение двух знаков в теме пояснения и считает их, как я думаю,  равноправными. Но для двоеточия требуется обязательное интонационное предупреждение, а для тире этого не нужно, вот и вся разница. Тире более свободный знак, поэтому и применяется чаще.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий**

Серж, мой ответ такой: **писатель имеет право поставить тире**, если  он хочет придать пояснительным отношениям  присоединительное значение и у него нет желания использовать предупредительную интонацию.  **Это его выбор, правила позволяют ему это сделать.**

Если же он захочет оставить пояснения на первом плане, то он поставит двоеточие.  Выбор писателя соответствует его **художественной задаче и общей ритмике текущего текста**, который мы в данном случае не видим, даже это важно.

Многие  считают, что тире  расширило свою функциональность  и стало активно применяться только в современной литературе. А вы посмотрите классику, ну и современную литературу посмотрите тоже – **тире применялось и раньше, а сейчас оно вообще значительно потеснило двоеточие.**  Ритм литературы стал другим – меньше в ней неспешных описаний и раздумий.

Да и в нашей обычной речи часто встречаются причинно-следственные отношения, а как мы их обозначаем? То запятой, то тире, а двоеточие в этой теме редко ставим. Другими словами (по Розенталю),  мы не делаем  в этом случае интонационного предупреждения и голос не останавливаем.

Поэтому не надо считать  присоединительное тире дополнительным знаком и искать в нем **дополнительные оттенки** – никто этого не делает и раньше не делал.  Это вполне равноправный с двоеточием знак даже в этих темах. Раньше строгих правил не было, но писатели **интуитивно понимали,** какой знак лучше поставить.

Честно говоря, мне кажется, что мы подгоняем действительность **под наши формальные правила** и  потом удивляемся, почему **не видим соответствия**.

Comment: Sharon, момент не по теме. "Бостон — Мэн", скорее всего, нужно написать с тире, а не с дефисом.

Comment: Спасибо.  А я чего, я  текст просто скопировала... Если бы милый редактор исправил бы и вопрос тоже, то я также охотно поставила бы тире.

Comment: Вот только не очень красиво смотрится (два тире), хотя кавычки сглаживают эту субъективную "некрасивость".

Comment: Ничего, читатели переживут... Я тоже было споткнулась об эти тире, но  другого выхода не вижу.

Comment: Моя вина с дефисом. Исправила.

Comment: @ОльгаАверина Почему же Ваша? Я нашел на [Литмире](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=177256&p=59) с дефисом. Или в Вашем источнике стоит тире?

Comment: В печатной книге у меня стоит тире.

Comment: О, замечательно!